# Hamburger menu lock scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've spend lot of time trying to lock the scroll when a hamburger menu is open. Is there a solution?

My code:

```
 <!-- Navigation bar -->
    <header class="header">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <a href="teste.html" class="logo"><img src="img/ss.png"></a>
        <!-- Hamburger icon -->
        <input class="side-menu" type="checkbox" id="side-menu" />
        <label class="hamb" for="side-menu"><span class="hamb-line"></span></label>
        <!-- Menu -->
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul class="menu" id="menu">
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="teste.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="servicos.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="contato.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li>
                    <input type="button" name="nome" value="FREE ESTIMATE">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To lock the scroll when the menu is open, you can use JavaScript to add a class to the body element when the menu is open and remove it when the menu is closed. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Your Page Title</title>
    <style>
        /* Your existing CSS styles */
        body.menu-open {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Navigation bar -->
<header class="header">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <a href="teste.html" class="logo"><img src="img/ss.png"></a>
    <!-- Hamburger icon -->
    <input class="side-menu" type="checkbox" id="side-menu" />
    <label class="hamb" for="side-menu"><span class="hamb-line"></span></label>
    <!-- Menu -->
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul class="menu" id="menu">
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="teste.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="servicos.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="contato.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li>
                <input type="button" name="nome" value="FREE ESTIMATE">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<!-- Your page content goes here -->

<script>
    // JavaScript to toggle the 'menu-open' class on the body element
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var sideMenu = document.getElementById('side-menu');
        var body = document.body;

        sideMenu.addEventListener('change', function () {
            if (sideMenu.checked) {
                body.classList.add('menu-open');
            } else {
                body.classList.remove('menu-open');
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In this example, I added a new style in the  section to hide the overflow when the body has the class menu-open. The JavaScript code uses an event listener to add or remove the class based on the state of the side menu checkbox. This way, the body's overflow will be hidden when the menu is open and restored when it's closed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post [is not permitted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) on Stack Overflow, even if you've validated this content. Also see the related [Help](/help/ai-policy) on this topic. We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable member of the community by contributing your own quality answers and questions in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the hamburger menu element so when it is clicked the function will be called:

```
onclick="hambClicked()"
```

Then in your script file, write the function:

```
let isScrollable= false;

function hamClicked() {
  if (isScrollable) {
    document.body.classList.remove('disabledScroll');
  } else {
    document.body.classList.add('disabledScroll');
  }

  isScrollable= !isScrollable;
}
```

And add this to your CSS file:

```
.disabledScroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You can use [.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle), which adds or removes a class, with a second boolean parameter "force" which forces an add when true or a remove when false — this eliminates the `if (isScollable)` and the almost-duplicated code to become the single statement `document.body.classList.toggle('disabledScroll', !isScrollable);`